# Simulating Keystrokes to a Telnet process

Tags: linux, scripting, python

On my Linux system I have opened a `Telnet` session. On the other tab I am running a `Python` script and giving commands to the `Telnet` session using `mkfifo` file redirection. But I am not able to simulate key presses to the `Telnet` session through my `Python` script.

Every command which I am trying to redirect to `Telnet` session is being done like this:

```
printf "ls" > my.fifo
```

But how can I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> using the same way?

People want more clarification so below i am giving a detailed explanantion

so in one tab i have opened a telnet session using these commands

```
mkfifo my.fifo
cat >my.fifo &
cat my.fifo | telnet 182.23.45.12 10000 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

Now in another tab i am running a python script which is giving commands to this telnet process. That I am doing through **printf "command" > my.fifo** .

But I need to send a key press event to the telnet process which i am not able to do using this below command

```
printf "command" > my.fifo
```

Clarification:
tty and pts are there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1) What exactly do you want this Ctrl+C to do? and where? (local or remote side?). (2) By "telnet session" do you mean a connection with a telnet client to a *telnet* server? i.e. everything by RFC 854, as opposed to using `telnet` to connect to a non-telnet ASCII-based server (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1461622/432690)) (3) Is there a tty on the remote side? What else is there? a shell?

Comment: (1) remote site
(2) client side
(3) yes tty and pts are there.

Comment: @roaima Can you please look now

Comment: With `printf "command"`, if the command contains a percent symbol (`%`) or a backslash (`\ `) it will be behave in a way that you're not expecting, because you're placing the command directly as the format string. Instead, use `printf '%s\n' "$command"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. First, I installed the obsolete `telnetd` and the associated `telnet`.

Then I created two FIFOs (one for input to the `telnet` command and the other for its output) and started the `telnet` process subshell. If you don't need to capture the output through a FIFO you can ignore all references to the output FIFO (`$f1`):

```
f1="$HOME/fifo1" f2="$HOME/fifo2"
mkfifo -m 600 "$f1" "$f2"
```

In another window (terminal) I arranged to read the output from the FIFO:

```
while :; do echo READING:; cat "$f1"; done
```

In yet another window (terminal) I entered commands to the running `telnet` session:

```
telnet localhost 2>"$f1" >"$f1" <"$f2"    # Attached stderr, stdout, stdin
exec 3>"$f2"                              # Hold open the FIFO
```

Then I logged in,

```
user=roaima    # Username
read pass      # Enter password here
( printf '%s\n' "$user"; sleep 1; printf '%s\n' "$pass" ) >"$f2"
```

Then I sent some commands

```
echo date >"$f2"
echo sleep 20 >"$f2"
```

Then I quickly interrupted the sleep  command

```
printf '\003' >"$f2"
```

Here's the session output:

```
READING:
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Raspbian GNU/Linux 11
pi login: roaima
Password:
Linux pi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l
[...]
pi:~$ date
Sat 11 Mar 11:57:15 GMT 2023
pi:~$ sleep 20
^C
pi:~$
```

As you can see, it simply worked for me. Sending `\003` as a character was treated by the server as the keyboard interrupt <kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>.

Comment: Suppose instead od ctrl + c i want ti simulate up arrow and down arrow key as i need to select boot option from grub menu. How will i do it as there is no control character for up arrow key.

Comment: "_there is no control character for up arrow key_" - yes there is. It depends on the terminal emulation expected by the destination

Comment: So, Instead of this \003  what should i use to simulate up arrow key behaviour?

Comment: It depends on the terminal emulation expected by the destination